# Navigation menu disappears when I hover the mouse

Tags: css, html

When I hover the mouse on submenu of our products section it automatically disappears, so I cannot click on the sub products. can you please help us out? [website](https://www.discreet.co.in)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> See in this screenshot http://prntscr.com/mldnem "li tag" is
>   padding with red border so it is max height to consider li tag to
>   hover sub menu if mouse cursor is go to below the red border then
>   sub-menu is automatically disappears. so you can either reduce the
>   font size of menu with padding or remove 2 items in menu then after
>   it's working fine. Hope you got proper solutions.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you brief how I can solve this error as I am new in css.

Comment: Yes, I will help you in CSS.

Comment: Thanks for your previous help. You solved my problem guru. However whenever I click on the primary menu there is no Emergency Station submenu image just like other products. I accidentally deleted its related file from media library. how can I recover that?